# Unable to update "data" using "computed" setters in vuejs(2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code -

```
Vue.component('competetion-list', {
  template: `<div><p>{{competition}}</p><p>{{totalCompetitions}}</p></div>`,
  props: ['values'],
  data: function () {
     return {totalCompetitions: this.values.length}
  },
  computed:{
    competition:{
      get: function(){
        return this.values.length;
      },
      set: function(){
        this.totalCompetitions = this.values.length;
      }
    } 
  } 
})
```

and the output I get is -

```
15
0
```

So, when I call `competition` it does return the length of the `values` prop but it doesn't set the length to `totalCompetition` and shows 0 which is the initiated value.

However, I was able to update `totalCompetition` through the `watch` property.

```
watch: {
   values: function(){
     this.totalCompetetions= this.values.length
   }
}
```

Now, my question is, why can't I update the `data` property values through `computed` setters while the getters can return the same?

Comment: At what point do you think your `set` function is getting called?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a `this`.

```
 computed:{
    competition:{
      get: function(){
        return this.values.length;
      },
      set: function(){
        this.totalCompetitions = this.values.length;
      }
    } 
  }
```

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish though from the code you posted. Right now, there is nothing that will execute the `set`. Typically a setter would accept a value

```
set: function(value){
    this.totalCompetitions = value;
}
```

And having your `get` work off a different value seems like working at cross purposes.

Possibly you want?

```
  data: function () {
     return {competitions: this.values}
  },
  computed:{
    totalCompetitions:{
      get: function(){
        return this.competitions.length;
      }
    } 
  } ,
```